# When a user is signing up, does Amazon cognito automatically check if their email already exists?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm a beginner with AWS Cognito, right now I'm implementing a lambda trigger for Pre Sign Up that checks if the email domain is valid. I'm using the AWS Lambda for Java library.

Q1. Will Cognito automatically check if the user email already exists?

Q2. If not, can Pre Sign Up have more than one trigger so I can implement one to check my user pools for the email address?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

Q1. Will Cognito automatically check if the user email already exists?

If you select email as alias during user pool set up, the email can be in verified state in only one account. Which means, if another user tries to sign up and confirm account with the same email address, service will check if the email is already exists and verified. If it is, service will throw AliasExistsException. 
Please see more details here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html#user-pool-settings-aliases

Q2. If not, can Pre Sign Up have more than one trigger?

Pre Sign Up can only have one trigger

Comment: Concerning the username, is it possible to have the mail serving as the user name ? I want to have my user to log with teir email